# FORTRAN subroutine thinks the length of a string I'm passing it is not what it is

Tags: fortran

stackoverflow.  First-time poster, long-time reader.  I am working on debugging a large program (that started in F77 but has evolved), and I'm getting a runtime error that the string I'm passing a subroutine is shorter than expected.  The thing is, I'm putting in a debug statement right before calling the subroutine, and the string is indeed of the correct length.  Can you help me figure this one out?  Since the code is long I'll just post the relevant snippet of file her1pro.F here (note WORD="HUCKEL " with a space at the end, but this happens to all the strings):

```
      SUBROUTINE PR1INT(WORD,WORK,LWORK,IORDER,NPQUAD,
     &                  TRIANG,PROPRI,IPRINT)
...
      CHARACTER WORD*7
...
      WRITE(*,*)"LB debug, calling PR1IN1 from PR1INT"
      WRITE(*,*)"LB debug, WORD=",WORD
      WRITE(*,*)"LB debug, LENGTH(WORD)=",LEN(WORD)
      CALL PR1IN1(WORK,KFREE,LFREE,WORK(KINTRP),WORK(KINTAD),
     &            WORK(KLBINT),WORD,IORDER,NPQUAD,TRIANG,
     &            PROPRI,IPRINT,DUMMY,NCOMP,TOFILE,'TRIANG',
     &            DOINT,WORK(KEXPVL),EXP1EL,DUMMY)
...
      SUBROUTINE PR1IN1(WORK,KFREE,LFREE,INTREP,INTADR,LABINT,WORD,
     &                  IORDER,NPQUAD,TRIANG,PROPRI,IPRINT,
     &                  SINTMA,NCOMP,TOFILE,MTFORM,
     &                  DOINT,EXPVAL,EXP1EL,DENMAT)

...
      CHARACTER LABINT(*)*8, WORD*7, TABLE(NTABLE)*7, MTFORM*6,
     &          EFDIR*1, LABLOC*8
...
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

```
[xxx@yyy WORK_TEST ]$ ~/dalton/build/dalton.x

 DALTON: default work memory size used.            64000000

 Work memory size (LMWORK+2):    64000002 =  488.28 megabytes; node   0

   0: Directories for basis set searches:
     ./:
 LB debug, calling PR1IN1 from PR1INT
 LB debug, WORD=HUCKEL
 LB debug, LENGTH(WORD)=           7
At line 161 of file /p/home/lbelcher/dalton/DALTON/abacus/her1pro.F
Fortran runtime error: Actual string length is shorter than the declared one for dummy argument 'word' (6/7)
```

Comment: We need to see much more (please read about a [mre]) to be able to help here: every `word` entity you currently show has length 7 (regardless of any value) and so the error message you present cannot make sense without further context.

Comment: I would suggest that you consider changing CHARACTER word*7 to be CHARACTER(LEN=7) :: WORD

Answer (score 1):

From the standard:

```
16.9.112 LEN (STRING [, KIND])
Description. Length of a character entity.
Class. Inquiry function.
Arguments.
STRING shall be of type character. If it is an unallocated allocatable variable or a pointer that is not associated, its length type parameter shall not be deferred.
KIND (optional) shall be a scalar integer constant expression.
Result Characteristics. Integer scalar. If KIND is present, the kind type parameter is that specified by the value of KIND; otherwise the kind type parameter is that of default integer type.
Result Value. The result has a value equal to the number of characters in STRING if it is scalar or in an element of STRING if it is an array.
Example. If C is declared by the statement
CHARACTER (11) C (100)
LEN (C) has the value 11.


16.9.113 LEN_TRIM (STRING [, KIND])
Description. Length without trailing blanks.
Class. Elemental function.
Arguments.
STRING shall be of type character.
KIND (optional) shall be a scalar integer constant expression.
Result Characteristics. Integer. If KIND is present, the kind type parameter is that specified by the value of KIND; otherwise the kind type parameter is that of default integer type.
Result Value. The result has a value equal to the number of characters remaining after any trailing blanks in STRING are removed. If the argument contains no nonblank characters, the result is zero.
Examples. LEN_TRIM (’ A B ’) has the value 4 and LEN_TRIM (’ ’) has the value 0.
```

I think the examples here tell the story.

Comment: Are you saying it has something to do with the trailing space?  It doesn't seem to, since I get the same error when WORD="OVERLAP"

Comment: No it has to do with the filled length end the declared length. The remark regarding `OVERLAP` I don't get, here I would expect twice 7 (at least when you didn't change (the old fashioned) declaration ``